# How to turn off resizing of applications windows when changing between workspaces?

Tags: windows, workspaces

There is an annoying "feature" in my Ubuntu Unity 11.10.

When I work in more than one workspace with several applications open, switching between workspaces allways resizes one of the application windows to maximum size - destroying my working layout and hiding the other open applications windows in the workspace.

Every time I switch workspace I need to resize one of the application windows.

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!